# How to resize an image using PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize a picture to a fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747101/resize-a-picture-to-a-fixed-size)

How to resize an image in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize a picture to a fixed size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747101/resize-a-picture-to-a-fixed-size) and many others

Comment: Hi sir if the uploaded file is less size than we have to resize what will do. I need fixed size images. if uploaded image is bigger or smaller I have to make it as a constat size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [the GD and Image functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), or - if you want something more than just that - a library like ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org), call it via exec("convert ...") from php, copy it to the desired location and access it.

Comment: Good suggestion, I've also used it. Requires exec() access for PHP though and many virtual hosting companies have denied it.

Comment: ImageMagick offers a PHP API so there is no need for a less secure `exec()`: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=bi9l24vaisg19eu5racue3gsh6#php

Comment: Through PHP API you've got a memory cap that kicks in pretty fast esp. considering the low memory of virtually hosted sites and users uploading their 10 MP images.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like I do and use a lightweight framework like flourishlib.com where everything is nicely wrapped in a class [fImage](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fImage), example from documentation:

```
// Saving as a 60 quality JPEG
$image2 = new fImage('./example.gif');
$image2->resize(250, 0);
$image2->saveChanges('jpeg', 60);
```

It will work with both GD and ImageMagick

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Image_Transform](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Transform) PEAR package for it. A ready-made thing that's pretty solid at this task.

Answer (score 0):

You may use codeigniter framework which provides you a lot of tools, including image manipulation. Otherwize, the main idea is to:

- open your picture (jpg for instance) with [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg)
- create a new picture using [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor)
- use [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)
- finally to save it with [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/imagejpeg).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to a [Image resize script](http://pastebin.com/DRyBaBZE) which i wrote a while back. It resizes the image and keeps the aspect ratio.

This script uses the core GD library to resize. So hopefully your host already got it installed.

I did some fast translation on the documentation from swedish to english. So it might not be perfect.

Hope it works!