# How can I "flip" an image using PHP?

Tags: php, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize an image using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004971/how-to-resize-an-image-using-php)

Here's what I've tried:

```
$image = "images/20100609124341Chrysanthemum.jpg"; 
$degrees = 40; 
// Content type 
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
// Load 
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
// Rotate 
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
// Output 
imagejpeg($rotate);
```

...But I get no output. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: You've already had 6 answers to your original question on resizing images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004971/how-to-resize-an-image-using-php so what have you done so far?

Comment: I am sorry for the previous post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the image rotate function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: $image = "images/20100609124341Chrysanthemum.jpg";

$degrees = 40;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

it does'nt out put any thing why?

Comment: First use "error_reporting(-1);" and then try without the header() function and see what error you are getting. You have to make sure the image is being loaded first and then you rotate and output.