# fixed size thumbnails like twitpic.com

Tags: php, resize

How do you create a fixed size (height / width) of images/thumbnails In GD?

I know there is a lot of php scripts out there but that just scale it and height/width will always be different size.

I like the thumbnail like twitpic.com and facebook

Comment: possible duplicate [ImageMagick or GD Libary for image resizing and thumbnail creation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277823/imagemagick-or-gd-libary-for-image-resizing-and-thumbnail-creation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize panoramic image to fixed size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157998/resize-panoramic-image-to-fixed-size)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the height and width of the image using [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

and then resize it using [imagecopyresized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

The rest is all the same basic work done with GD to load and save the image.

Here's a basic example, if you want to take into account height/width ratios, then you have to do some additional maths.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$size = getimagesize($filename);
$image     = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$thumbnail = imagecreate(100,100);
imagecopyresized($thumbnail, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $size[0], $size[1]);
imagepng($thumbnail);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($thumbnail);
```

Comment: Thanks but I do know about this. Image look terrible when it resize to fixed hight and width. Need a way to crop specific area and then resize it. Just like twitpic.com

Comment: if you want it to look proportionate then you have to get copy from a portion of the image that has the same height/width ratio. e.g. to make a 100x100 thumbnail from a 200x300 image, you need to take 200x200 of that image. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with [Thumbnailer](http://freelogic.pl/thumbnailer/demo):

```
$th=new Thumbnailer("your-photo.jpg");
$th->thumbSquare(100)->save("thumb.jpg");
```