# Wordpress - add image size scale image with predefined width?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a solution to add an scaled down image for wordpress, I've been trying with add_image_size options I found in documents, but without success.

What I want to accomplish is to have a new image created with some reference, with predefined width (let's say 400), and height to be automatically scaled down as well. I still want to keep the original image on server and use it.

Is this possible?

P.s. i guess it should be something like:

```
add_image_size( 'new-image', 400 );
```

Comment: To better understand, you want to have two of the same image on the server, just one scaled down?

Comment: Have you add the line of code above in the `functions.php` file of your theme?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216672/php-resize-and-save-an-image Should be the fix you are looking for.