# How to resize an image from android via php before saving to server

Tags: php, android, image-resizing

I have gotten the code to take an image from android and save it to my server, however I need to resize the image to a standard size. I have looked around and have not been able to get anything to work. Below is my code so far.

```
<?php
    // Get image string
    $base = $_REQUEST['image'];

    // Get file name
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

    // Decode Image
    $binary = base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    // Images will be saved
    $file = fopen('/home1/skyrealm/public_html/img/'.$filename.'.jpg', 'wb');
    if($file != true)
    {
        echo'Error uploading image';
    }
    else
    {
        // Create/Svae File
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);
        echo 'Image upload successful';
    }
?>
```

EDIT:

This is the code android side:

```
public void encodeImagetoString() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

            // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
            params.put("image", encodedString);

            // Trigger Image upload
            triggerImageUpload();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want sth like this http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php , although you still need to save it first!

Comment: Why do you want to upload the full size image from Android app to server and then resize using php? It's a bad practice, cos it consumes more band-width for both app users and your server. Rather, resize the image from the app, then upload to server and just save using php.

Comment: Dont you like to resize it using android's Bitmap Factory

Comment: added my android code. Still not sure how to permanently resize the image.

Comment: Why are you sending it as base64? Also why are you setting a header for images if you're echoing text out?

Comment: base 64 as its social and wanted everything private. header because i thought that was necessary

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments you dont need `header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');` if you don't came out with the image itself.

About the resize the script is more or less fine just use [Imagemagic](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) or the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) .

Some post about resizing:
[php - resize and save an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216672/php-resize-and-save-an-image)